# Testacular error: Cannot start chrome

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am going through AngularJS tutorials, and I am stuck on the tutorial for running Testacular tests. I get the following error:

```
Starting Testacular Server (http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
info: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/
info (launcher): Starting browser Chrome
error (launcher): Cannot start Chrome
    execvp(): No such file or directory

info (launcher): Trying to start Chrome again.
error (launcher): Cannot start Chrome
    execvp(): No such file or directory

info (launcher): Trying to start Chrome again.
error (launcher): Cannot start Chrome
    execvp(): No such file or directory
```

When I search for the problem, there are similar users that have this problem but they are using Windows. I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: Please check whether the port is in use or not. Try this command [lsof -i | grep 9876]

Comment: @sza The port isn't in use. When I grep for it, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a small problem in config files' list of browsers. You should change the name of the browser in the configuration files under config/ directory: config/testacular.conf.js and testacular-e2e.conf.js.
If you are using chromium browser set the list of browsers to 'chromium-browse', instead of 'Chrome' like this.:

```
browsers = ['chromium-browser'];
```

Here is an ss of my testacular.conf.js file: [image: an ss of my testacular.conf.js].

If you would like to include more than one browser for you tests you can add the name of the other browsers installed in your system:

```
browsers = ['chromium-browser', 'firefox'];
```

If you are not sure about the name of your chrome browser this should help in the terminal:

```
ls /usr/bin/ | grep -i chrom
```