# How to get Karma to work with Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, angularjs, ubuntu, karma-runner

I have a command-line-only Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.35.4-rscloud x86_64) and I'm working through the [Angular Phonecat tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02#tests) which uses the Karma for testing. The [Karma browser config page](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/browsers.html) says Chrome launcher is "shipped with Karma by default."

But it's not working for me. [This is the karma.conf.js](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/b8f9f997564ea9de46431e0a0313f22921517e63/config/karma.conf.js). Below is the output.

```
 $ ./scripts/test.sh

Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.4 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
        Can not find the binary google-chrome
        Please set env variable CHROME_BIN
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625065/2812810) points out that I need chromium.

So I tried to install Chrome on my Ubuntu with [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/) with "download 64 bit version using command line". Everything went well until `sudo apt-get -f install`, which ended with a lot of "failed to fetch" from ubuntu IP addresses, such as 91.189.91.15 or 91.189.92.*. Even with /usr/bin/google*something* that the "Can not find the binary google-chrome" goes away, I still got the "Cannot start Chrome" on the individual test level. Then while trying to fix errors, I deleted /usr/bin/google*something*.

Currently, I have these node_modules:

```
angular-phonecat/node_modules$ ls
karma                      karma-html2js-preprocessor  karma-requirejs
karma-chrome-launcher      karma-jasmine               karma-script-launcher
karma-coffee-preprocessor  karma-junit-reporter
karma-firefox-launcher     karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

**Q 1: Since my machine has only command-line access, no GUI, is the other Karma launcher, PhantomJS, a better choice than Chrome/Chromium?**

Q 2: If I should still use Chrome/Chromium, should I get Chrome or Chromium?

Q 3: Does anyone know what exactly do I need to get google-chrome or chromium for Karma to work in the Angular app?

Comment: Thanks! I wish my logs would mention ```Please set env variable ``` **CHROME_BIN**, like yours did (BTW, on Windows try "`C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`", without quotes)

Answer (score 33):

I'll expand on Ludwig's third point for answer seekers and for my own reference in the future...

The first thing you need to do is find where `chromium-browser` is installed. Run:

```
which chromium-browser
```

This will return the path to the executable, which will look something like this:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Then simply set the path:

```
export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Now Karma can find the browser it needs to execute your tests (assuming you've decided to use a graphical interface).

Comment: I find your answer more readable then Ludwig's : I like the fact that I can copy-paste the export command (and that it just works afterwards). You could maybe go one step further and explain how to automatically reload that export variable using a .bashrc for instance.

Comment: If you are a newbie to karma (which is probably why you are reading this) it's helpful to know that karma with Chromium requires a graphics display.  It conveniently hides the 'cannot open display' error message which would be trying to tell you that your DISPLAY environment variable is not set to use some running X Windows server.

Answer (score 10):

1. If you only have a command-line interface, PhantomJS is the only choice for you.
2. In linux (at least 12.04 and forwards) chromium is the alternative. But you can't install it if you don't have a graphical ui.
3. The clue is here: "Please set env variable CHROME_BIN". Karma tries to execute a file called `google-chrome` and it does not exist. The name of the executable for chrome varies from OS to OS. Therefore you need to set an enviroment variable called CHROME_BIN which has the value of the name of your chrome executable. On my system (Linux desktop 13.10) this is `chromium-browser`.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to create an alias in linux to windws's chrome

```
alias launchchrome="\"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\""
```

and after that export that alias as linux env variable

```
export CHROME_BIN=launchchrome
```

That's it, now if you run `ng test` your windows chrome will be used! In my particular case this solution worked

Comment: I'm about a year late, but I just came across this question this morning and this is exactly what I needed as I'm running Windows Subsystem for Linux ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I set up a project with [the yeoman generator angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) today, I couldn't get chrome or phantomjs to work with karma either.

It turns out this is [an issue specific to that project](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/633#issuecomment-39652467) and the fix is simply adding the missing plugins to the package.json in your project root.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is not maintained anymore[1] and therefore not a good choice.

On Ubuntu/Debian I wasn't able to get Karma running on Chrome, either. So I tried Firefox and that worked. If you want to use Firefox, too, make sure Firefox is installed and then place the following lines in your karma.conf.js:

```
customLaunchers: {
    firefox_headless: {
        base: 'Firefox',
        flags: ['--headless']
    }
},
browsers: ['firefox_headless'],
```

[1] https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344