# Is it possible to run Karma with no browsers at all?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I started an Angular.js app with Yeoman's `yo angular` that includes Karma testing. Then, the `grunt test` reasonably failed because [Karma can't find any browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093148/cannot-start-chrome-error-with-yeoman). (The `browsers` has not been set in the app's node_modules/karma config file.)

I'm doing my development via SSH into a remote machine, which I think (let me know if I'm wrong) is pointless to have Chrome, `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`, installed.

So is it possible to run Karma without any browsers?

Comment: Why not make use of PhantomJS instead of Chrome?

Comment: Good point. I think I'll get that. But is it possible to run Karma without any browsers?

Comment: No, Karma does need a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. You can put that comment as an answer and get points. Btw, your quote is so encouraging: "The biggest satisfaction for a great programmer is when he doesn't understand." :)

Comment: Yes :) Very encouraging ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Karma **needs** a browser to be set.

You can make use of PhantomJS instead of Chrome.
Indeed, it's more discreet than a traditional browser launch.

Comment: This comment is posted on 2014, it still needs browser ?

Comment: Yes it still requires it. You might want to consider Mocha if you don't want any browser.

Comment: Keep scrolling...the real answer is down below.

Comment: PhantomJS is no longer maintained. Avoid to use it.

Comment: Im suffering from the consequences now, upgrading to Angular 9. Use `ChromeHeadless`

Answer (score 45):

I am going to add my two cents to this.

Correct - Karma requires a browser to run. BUT - you can run Chrome in Headless mode, which means although you do need the browser installed, it will not open it's UI, and you can therefore run the tests purely through an SSH session for example.

We used this configuration for our CI/CD deployments. Our Docker image for running the tests had Chrome installed and we ran them with Chrome headless mode. Worked like a charm.

To use this, simply modify your `browsers` property in your `karma.conf.js`

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']
```

Hope this might help someone out there who may be looking for something similar...

Comment: `ChromeHeadless` is the answer. This should be at the top.

Answer (score 13):

This question and answer is very relevant as of today (soon 2018, > angular2, @angular/cli, typescript, ...).

Here is a small update, based on what i found as useful on the net:

Say you have an `angular cli` generated project that has not been tempered with. Say you want to use `PhantomJS` to run your angular2 tests (nothing shocking).

Start by installing `PhantomJS` launcher for Karma in your project

```
npm i --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

Next you have to update the `karma.conf.js` file as follows:

First the the plugins properties:

```
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
],
```

Then the browser properties

```
browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ],
```

Running the test at this point, you will probably stumble on the following error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: pre,template,textarea,script,style is not iterable!
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:792
```

Basically, that means your `PhantomJS` needs different polyfills. Uncomment the following lines in your `src\polyfills.ts`

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Last but not least, here are the links that helped me work this out:

[How to run jasmine tests without browser ?](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2013)

[New angular-cli app not working on iphone 4s](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7835)

Comment: Avoid using it, PhantomJS is not supported anymore

Comment: @LevKolomazov what is an alternative then?

Comment: @MarcusCantu https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jsdom-launcher