# Unit testing angular apps without launching a browser

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Im using yeoman + angular generator and hate the fact that I have to launch a browser EVERYTIME i want to test, and I test very frequently. Is there a way I can run tests with just the console without having to wait for Karma to find and launch a browser (taking 8 seconds on current laptop). Or do I need to try another testing library? Take in mind im only testing controller logic, not form input etc.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895984/is-it-possible-to-run-karma-with-no-browsers-at-all

Comment: whoops :) thank you Neo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using some headless frameworks like Zombie (http://zombie.labnotes.org/) or PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/)